# I am trying to make a Fraction Calculator in HTML Javascript, I need to simplify the fraction how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator, fractions

The non script part of my calculator is this (With all the inputs):

```
<body>
    <p class="box">Fraction Calculator</p>
    <input type="number" id="n1">
    <select id="operation">
        <option value="1">X</option>
        <option value="2">/</option>
        <option value="3">+</option>
        <option value="4">-</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" id="n2">
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="n3">
    <input type="number" id="n4" style="margin-left:37px">
    <br>
    <button style="margin-left:130px"; onClick="document.getElementById('fraction').innerHTML = option()">Go!</button>
    <p id="fraction"></p>
</body>
```

And my option function is this:

```
function option()
 {
 selection = document.getElementById('operation').value;


 if(selection == "1"){

 a = multiply();
 return a
 }
 else if(selection == "2"){
 b = division();
 return b
 }
 else if(selection == "3"){
 c = addition();
 return c
 }
 else{
 d = subtraction();
 return d
 }
 }
```

So my current  code for my multiplication part fo my calculator is this:

```
 function multiply()
 {
 Number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
 Number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
 Number3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n3").value);
 Number4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n4").value);


 var topm = Number1 * Number2;
 var botm = Number3 * Number4;
 return topm + "/" + botm; }
```

So currently my calculator works but none of the fractions are simplified. How would I be able to simplify these fractions? (I am decently new to code) Thanks :) 
Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ethang70/npgL3gd9/

Comment: I really hope you indent your code and it git lost during upload, also, include a JSFiddle

Comment: Okay it did copy weird, anyway the JSFiddle link has been added or here (https://jsfiddle.net/Ethang70/npgL3gd9/)

Comment: Maybe just search about fractions simplification algorithm...
http://www.jstor.org/stable/41187600?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify fractions, what you do is that you calculate the greatest common divisor between the denominator and numerator, and divide both with the GCD.

One way to calculate the GCD is to use the [Eucledian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

One implementation in Javascript could be:

```
 function gcd(a,b)
 { 
   if (b == 0)
   {
     return a;
   }
   else
   {
     return gcd(b, a % b);
   }
}
```

And thereafter, when you print your fraction you can do something like this:

```
function multiply()
{
  Number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
  Number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
  Number3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n3").value);
  Number4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n4").value);

  var topm = Number1 * Number2;
  var botm = Number3 * Number4;
  var divisor = gcd(topm, botm);
  topm = topm / divisor;
  botm = botm / divisor;
  return topm + "/" + botm;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a small third-party script, you could take a look at [fraction.js](https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js/). As per @Zyberzero's answer, it calculates the greatest common divisor of a non-integer and returns it as the lowest fraction it can make as a string:

```
var myNum = 0.5;
var fraction = new Fraction(myNum);
console.log(fraction.toString()); // Returns 1/2
```

If the result is an integer, it will return the same integer. If the result *contains* an integer, it will return in the format `int d/n`; so if you want just the fraction, you can split around the space.

It depends how low you want to go, though; there are certain decimal values that notionally represent fractions, but can't be divided to the 'lowest' fraction that you might want. For example, `0.3333333333...`  ostensibly represents one third, but fractions.js would (correctly) return `33/100`. In my most recent use-case, I wanted particular low fractions like `1/3`, `1/9`, `2/3` etc. (based on decimal values like `0.33`, `0.11`, `0.66`) so I wrote a quick & dirty `if/else` to give me the lower fractions I was after:

```
var fractionString = fraction.toString();

var singleQuantity = '';

if (fractionString.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
    var quantitySplit = fractionString.split(' ');
    var fractionSplit = quantitySplit[1].split('/');

    singleQuantity = quantitySplit[0] + ' ';
    topFraction = parseInt(fractionSplit[0]);
    bottomFraction = parseInt(fractionSplit[1]);
}

if (bottomFraction == 100) {
    switch (topFraction) {
        case 11 : {
            topFraction = 1;
            bottomFraction = 9;
            break;
        }
        case 33 : {
            topFraction = 1;
            bottomFraction = 3;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (bottomFraction == 50) {
    switch (topFraction) {
        case 33 : {
            topFraction = 2;
            bottomFraction = 3;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```